# What's the difference between install-powerpc and install-free-powerpc? "install-free"?

Tags: system-installation, powerpc, free, yaboot

I'm not sure which one to type in, and I can't find any info online that explains the difference.  I'm afraid the difference may be very important.

I noticed there's also "install" and "install-free", so I'm also not able to find what the difference there is.

Seen in [yaboot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaboot) after pressing {tab}.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but you'll have to be more specific. Where do you see it? What gives you these options?

Comment: Thank you.  As seen on "press tab" from the lubuntu desktop 14.04 CD (first screen, where you type "install" to install the OS).

Comment: So your architecture is PowerPC? We in the x86 lands usually do not have to type anything during installation time. But I think I can guess: "install" is probably the installation-only mode and "install-free" must be the "try without installing" options. But I'm just guessing.

Comment: @EduardoCola It's very odd.  The release is specifically for powerPC's, http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/ (sorry, I *am* using the alternate bc I don't have network access).  However, I have to type install-powerpc?  I wonder if it makes any difference.

Comment: Could you send images of your screen from boot time to the one you get this prompt in?

Comment: @EduardoCola I'll get a picture after the OS loads up.  If you press "tab" at the first screen after you put a Ubuntu CD in, it enumerates kernel install options.

Comment: So why don't you just select one of the defaults?

Comment: Well, I'm using a powerpc. The default is "install", and then there's also the install-powerpc.  I'm confused, but in my mind it makes more sense to type install-powerpc because perhaps install will install an OS purposed for another hardware through this hardware....  Only explanation I can come up with, since I don't know the gory details about how any of this works.

Comment: I would think that `install-free` means it doesn't come with any proprietary components, but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Can you elaborate?  It's a mac. isn't everything proprietary?

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 hardware is, but what you're installing isn't necessarily.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about there being a major difference. Just go with that normal one (install).

Comment: @Zacharee1 http://superuser.com/questions/1028206/include-network-drivers-on-a-mini-cd-probook-g4-lubuntu-black-screen-with

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 Did you try `install video=ofonly`, like the prompt suggests?

Comment: @Zacharee1 The "white screen" looks different.  There's no mouse cursor on that screen, which indicates that the video driver couldn't be found.  I've got a black screen with a mouse cursor.

Comment: Try it anyway. Who knows?

Comment: @Zacharee1 Hoping the triaged/unresolved bug method or the 'use a liveOS' method works (next step).

Comment: Try it I guess. How long did you left the computer after it booted?

Comment: @Zacharee1 Bout twenty minutes.  Eventually, the monitor started flashing on and off with a text cursor at the top left (black screen).  I'm wondering if the -free- switch won't work, but I'd really like to just try loading the correct files into an ISO; however, I can't figure out for the life of me how to do that.  I'm getting the "known bug" like a billion times.

Comment: I'm not that good with PPC, and I've tried to install Lubuntu multiple times on my old 1999 G3. It's never even reached the installer phase.

Comment: update: it's yaboot, not ubiquity

Answer (score 3):

The "install-free" option from yaboot adds `apt-setup/restricted=false apt-setup/multiverse=false` to the kernel command line. These two options disable non-free or multiverse software during the installation.